# Redirecting to Python program to Terminal and file

Tags: python, linux, bash, terminal

This is very weird that "tee" is not working for the python scripts.
I have a program called "test.py" and trying to output to the terminal and to a log file using shell commands. 
I have tried

```
$python test.py | tee -a result.txt
$python test.py | tee result.txt
$python test.py | >> result.txt
$ (python test.py) | tee -a result.txt
```

It just does not work.
I do not want to change anything in my program cause there are more than 200 print statements.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "it just does not work"?

Comment: How is the script generating output?

Comment: Your lines 1, 2 and 4 work fine on my end, so you're going to have to be more specific.

Comment: I am using basic "print" statements in the program..
Now that I wait for the program, its dumping 100s of statements at once.

Comment: I did not wait for the program to run..
But dumping 100s of statement is also not what  I want...

Comment: If your program "dumps 100s of statements" but you don't want that, it's not an issue with `tee`... you need to modify your code.

Answer (score 1):

From @kqr below, run it in unbuffered mode:

```
python -u test.py | tee result.txt
```

Comment: Does the same thing.. It takes around 30-40 seconds to display on the terminal by dumping 100s of statement at once.

Comment: @user2452845 It sounds like your program is waiting for a while and then flushing the output. You can try peppering it with `stdout.flush()` statements, but it sounds like a logic issue and not a buffering issue. Can't really say without seeing any code.

Comment: I suspect Python automatically detects it is run non-interactively (in a pipe) and applies some heavy buffering to be more performant. [This might help.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering)